# How to get dropdown selected id on ng-repeat in angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-ng-repeat

By using this code am I able to get dropdown id (If I comment `ng-repeat`)

```
<tr @*ng-repeat="r in rvm"*@ @*>
    <td>
        <select ng-model="ID" ng-options="c.ID as c.Name for c in customer" ng-change="GetAccountBalance($index)" style="width:150px;height:22px;" name=" tCustomer">
            <option value="">Select Customer</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

javascript

```
 $scope.GetAccountBalance = function (index) {
    var getAccountBalance = ReceiptsService.GetAccountBalance($scope.ID);
    var id = $scope.ID;
    alert(id);
 }
```

But my requirement is adding new row on dropdown change

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in rvm">
    <td>
        <select ng-model="ID" ng-options="c.ID as c.Name for c in customer" ng-change="GetAccountBalance($index)" style="width:150px;height:22px;" name=" tCustomer">
            <option value="">Select Customer</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

javascript

```
$scope.rvm = [{}];

$scope.GetAccountBalance = function (index) {
    if ($scope.rvm.length == (index + 1)) {
        $scope.rvm.push({});
    }
}
var getAccountBalance = ReceiptsService.GetAccountBalance($scope.ID);
var id = $scope.ID;
alert(id);
```

Am I able to add new row by using this code , but I'm not getting selected id,
how to selected dropdown id?
If I remove `ng-repeat` I'm getting id ,